# Hibernate enhance fails for OneToOne mapping using foreign key association

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one

I did quite a bit of research based on the exception I received from hibernate-enhance, but no answers exist.

I have a OneToOne mapping with foriegn key association defined as shown below:

```
public class A {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_B", nullable = false)
    private B request;

}
```

and then a foriegn key in the db script like this:

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD CONSTRAINT A_B_FK FOREIGN KEY
(
    A_B
)
REFERENCES
B
(
  IDE_COMMN_REQUEST
) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

when I run my build, it fails with the error below:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.hibernate.orm.tooling:hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin:5.1.0.Final:enhance
>   (default) on project projectAB: Unable to enhance class:
>   com.data.entities.report.A: Unable to enhance persistent attribute
>   [com.data.entities.report.A:request]: Could not enhance entity class
>   [com.data.entities.report.A] to add field writer method
>   [$$_hibernate_write_request]: [source error]
>   $$_hibernate_write_instances(com.data.entities.report.A) not found in
>   com.data.entities.report.content.B

I do not see anything wrong in the way the mapping is defined (I have cross checked with OneToOne mapping examples on internet.) I am not sure if something is missing!!

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you solve the issue?